# Is there a way to overcome the bug in "A New Source of Stalhrim" in PS3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, skyrim-dragonborn

I can't start the quest "A New Source of Stalhrim" by talking to  Deor Woodcutter (instead of giving me the quest he just says general things). The [Unnoficial Elder Scroll Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:A_New_Source_of_Stalhrim) states that it's a bug that can be fixed in PC using the command line but I'm playing in PS3. Even worse: I was not aware of this bug until I tried to get the quest, so if I use an old saved game I'll have to restart eveything I did in Solstheim (and I just have killed Miraak - not to mention some other quests). Is there a way to overcome this bug in PS3?

Comment: one of the most common 'bug fixers' on the console is the use of the wabbajack, have you tried using that yet?

Comment: Good idea! I don't have Wabbajack yet but as soon as I get it I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the Wabbajack but it didn't work... Any other idea?

Comment: unfortunately that's about all you can do other than a reload on the console

Comment: well, shouldn't it have autosaved after you killed him? Just load that save.

Answer (score 2):

Simply saying, **no, there isn't**.

Since you don't have access to console on the PS3 and the Wabbajack isn't working for you, you don't have any other way to make it work other than loading a previously saved file. As Vofun said, there might be a autosave file just after you killed Miraak, maybe you can try loading that.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new save file,kill Deor and then reload the save file?It somehow worked on another quest that had the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also playing with PS3 and had the same bug. I managed to fix it by using Unrelenting Force and Wabbajack on Deor. I don't know which one fixed it, but I had to use those several times on him. Give it a try. Hope this helps.